# Requests.Get fails on one server but works on another

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, python-requests

I have the following Python 2.7 code:

```
import requests
from urllib3 import Retry

s = requests.Session()

http_retries = Retry(3)
https_retries = Retry(3)

http = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=http_retries)
https = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=https_retries)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36',}

s.mount('http://', http)
s.mount('https://', https)

response = s.get(URL, headers=headers, timeout=10)
```

I keep getting

> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'

when I run script from Amazon AWS Instance but on another network it works fine.

Any idea why

Comment: I'd wager that your AWS configuration is the cause. E.g do the two instances have different security groups/policies regarding outbound traffic?

Comment: I think the problem was actually on the server. They seemed to be blocking traffic from all Amazon AWS IP addresses for some reason. From the AWS instance, `wget`, `curl` all failed but `ping` worked.